# Blender Is Not Rendering, Why?

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm trying to render an animation, the problem is Blender is not rendering anything. The CPU is not working at all, what to do?

Here's the file that I'm trying to render: [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wvoP3ShSEEMcd7sjs1WYHTuOqw2ZzNEM/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please don't make the question depend exclusively on others downloading your file and reverse-engineer what you did. Edit your question and explain clearly what you've done, add images of your render and output settings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a file format to output. You have a location but there is no output format. You need to choose .jpeg, .jpeg movie, MMPEG.... however you want you output to be.

It's in the output tab right above colors under "File Format" underneath where you select your output folder.

What version are using and which render are you trying to use: Blender, Cycles, Evee, Workbench..

Comment: I've set the file format, the output folder, encoding...etc. My Blender is 2.83 LTS and the render engine is Evee.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your output folder, and below that three lines down change your "FILE FORMAT" so Blender knows how to output.

Other then that I think it's trying to render your "FIRST MONITOR" which is nothing. All your information is on the second monitor. I can get it to "render" but there's nothing to render.

What I don't understand is why it's all black. Unless this is just Blenders way of saying I have nothing to render. It's actually popular in game programming IDE'S.

Unfortunately, I'll have to take a closer look a bit later. Good luck mean time.